# Как передать данные формы без обновления страницы?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

На сайте отправка писем осуществляется через атрибут action и PHPmailer (файл mail.php). Нужен скрипт, который бы заменил атрибут action, и отменил бы переадресацию на файл mail.php.

Пробовал такой вариант, но он не работает:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
 $(".test-form").submit(function () {
     e.preventDefault();
 // Получение ID формы
 var formID = $(this).attr('id');
 // Добавление решётки к имени ID
 var formNm = $('#' + formID);
 $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: 'mail.php',
 data: formNm.serialize(),
 success: function (data) {
 // Вывод текста результата отправки
 $(formNm).html(data);
 },
 error: function (jqXHR, text, error) {
 // Вывод текста ошибки отправки
 $(formNm).html(error);
 }
 });
 return false;
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас `this` и `e` ссылаются непонятно на что. Для отмены стандартного действия достаточно использовать `return false` (без всяких `preventDefault`). То есть вы можете сделать следующим образом: написать функцию отправки (передавая в нее `e`) и вызывать ее при нажатии на кнопку, а следом `return false`.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
      $(".test-form").submit(function (e) {
           sendForm(e);
           return false;
      });
 });

 function sendForm (e) {
      var formElem = $(e);
      $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: 'mail.php',
           data: formElem.serialize(),
           success: function (data) {
                // Вывод текста результата отправки
                formElem.html(data);
           },
           error: function (jqXHR, text, error) {
                // Вывод текста ошибки отправки
                formElem.html(error);
           }
      });
 }
```

Кроме того, возможно, вам больше понравится вот такая краткая форма для ajax, существующая в jQuery:

```
dataObject = formNm.serialize(); // объект с данными для отправки
$.post('mail.php', dataObject, function (data) {
    // Выполнится в случае успеха
});
```

Для обработки ошибки можно сделать так (начиная с версии 1.5, $.post() возвращает объект jqXHR):

```
var jqXHR = $.post('mail.php', dataObject, function (data) {
    // Выполнится в случае успеха
}).fail(function () {
    // Выполнится в случае ошибки
);
```

Comment: В консоли появляется ошибка http://prntscr.com/mj3ed7

Comment: @PavelBogdanov странно, что эта ошибка появилась (ведь этот метод объявлен в jQuery)... у вас jQuery точно правильно подключен? (желательно до main.js даже)

Comment: @PavelBogdanov попробуйте использовать обычную версию библиотеки (не slim): https://code.jquery.com/

Comment: Да, теперь все работает. Огромное спасибо!